# How to BREAK code after running for a specific number of times? [Python]

Tags: python

```
import random

results= ['Heads','Tails']
answers= ['Y','y','YES','yes']
result= random.choice(results)
counter = 0

print("Welcome to coin flippin' Mania")
question1= input("Flip coin? ")
question2= int(input("How many times? "))

while question1 in answers:
    print("\n\nThe coin landed on: %s" % result)
    counter +=1
    if counter == question2:
        break
```

As you can see, I've only started to write code, and the code you see above isn't very good. I want to be able to tell the computer the number of times it should "flip the coin," I've tried some methods, but can't find an answer.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @KindStranger I couldn't tell the computer how many times to run the code, it would run infinitely, or just print the same answer as many times as I told it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, while loop breaks based on user input. I think this is what you are looking for , put the `result` inside the while loop so you get the random choice for every flip

```
import random

results= ['Heads','Tails']
answers= ['Y','y','YES','yes']
counter = 0

print("Welcome to coin flippin' Mania")
question1= input("Flip coin? ")
question2= int(input("How many times? "))

while question1 in answers:
    result = random.choice(results)
    print("\n\nThe coin landed on: %s" % result)
    counter +=1
    if counter == question2:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just had to move one line... well that's coding for you... I guess

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, glad it helped. Dont forget to accept the answer Gabriel.